# jQuery manipulating select box while ignoring optgroups

Tags: jquery, optgroup

I've been stuck on this for quite some time now, not being able to solve it myself. Say I have this select:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
      <option>Dallas Cowboys</option>
      <option>New York Giants</option>
      <option>Philadelphia Eagles</option>
      <option>Washington Redskins</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="NFC NORTH">
      <option>Chicago Bears</option>
      <option>Detroit Lions</option>
      <option>Green Bay Packers</option>
      <option>Minnesota Vikings</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

and I have two buttons - next and prev. If someone clicks next then the next option is selected and vice versa. The problem I'm having is - how do I **completely ignore** the optgroups in this scenario? (i.e. if `Chicago Bears` is selected, pressing previous should select `Washington Redskins`).

[here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvii/U9hFV/1/) that illustrates the issue. I've tried many solutions but all of them got messy pretty fast. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**.index()**](http://api.jquery.com/index/), it searches for a given element from among the matched elements.

```
$('#next').on('click', function () {
    var selected = $('select option:selected');
    var index = $('select option').index(selected);
    var value = $('select option').eq(index + 1).val();
    $('select').val(value);
});

$('#prev').on('click', function () {
    var selected = $('select option:selected');
    var index = $('select option').index(selected);
    var value = $('select option').eq(index - 1).val();
    $('select').val(value);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MgB83/1/)

Comment: This is my favorite answer. It's clean and logical, and I'm not using any `if` conditions or logic (and it's also goes in a loop which is a neat bonus)

Answer (score 2):

You can just check if the prev or next `option` exists, if not, do some logic, if so, use it (here's a sample with previous)

```
$('#prev').on('click', function() {
    var current = $('select option:selected'),
        previous = current.prev("option");

    if (previous.length)
        $('select').val(previous.val());
    else
        $('select').val(current.closest("optgroup").prev("optgroup").find("option:last").val());
});
```